# Different output from lynx -dump when run as cron job

Tags: cron, lynx

For a couple of years now I've been "scraping," using `lynx -dump`, content from a web page containing non-latin characters. I save the page content to a file, which I then modify via the agency of sed, and send that in the body of an e-mail--all this happening in a script I created. But I'm finding, after switching distros (Ubuntu to Void) that my script is not working as expected. I've identified the point of failure, as follows.

When I run the very first part of my script (the part containing `lynx -dump URL` and the file name to which the content is to be saved) from the command line, all works as expected. The file shows up and contains the non-latin characters I'm expecting. However when I try to automate the process by stipulating that same command as a cron job, the results are different. The expected file does show up, but instead of containing the expected non-latin characters, what I get is the same text transliterated using latin characters--not what I want. What follows in my script is failing since it depends on the presence of the non-latin characters.

So, why these strange results depending on whether I issue the lynx command from the command line as opposed to in a cron job? Perhaps the site is doing some sort of detection and providing a transliterated page in one case but not in the other? Or is lynx itself doing the transliterating of non-latin characters into latin ones? Input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lynx` uses the current locales to determine the charset it can use for showing pages.  This information is probably not available from `cron` however, so you need to do something like this:

```
lynx -display_charset=UTF-8 -dump http://example.com/some/page.html
```

(of course, use the charset on your system if different from UTF-8).

Comment: Adding that switch to the cron command did, in fact, resolve the issue--thanks! Though this is the more immediate resolution to the issue I'm seeing, I wonder whether a more fundamental resolution might not lie in Thomas Dickey's response. I can't say I really understand well how the whole locale thing works and its possible impact on what I'm trying to do, so I need to look into that further. After that I'll revisit this thread and try to decide which answer to mark as the solution.

Comment: Both solutions do essentially the same thing.  Read the comments in `lynx.cfg` for `CHARACTER_SET` and `LOCALE_CHARSET`.  Read `man lynx `for `-display_charset`. Also, use `wget` or `curl` instead of `lynx` if you want a "more fundamental resolution".

Comment: I did not try fiddling with the lynx options since I figured that, if those do not interfere when I run this script as my user, they also should not interfere when my user's cron job runs. But they obviously do. Rather than poroviding a solution, I think maybe Thomas Dickey might have been trying to point me toward something along the lines of what's described at  http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/ - correct?

Comment: Setting locales for `cron` jobs is a security hazard.  There's a reason why they are disabled by default. _shrug_

Comment: I prefer feeding to lynx the switch mentioned, so I will not be modifying /etc/environment. I looked into the possibility of using `wget` or `curl`, btw, but parsing the output I would get using those to create a basic text file such as what I'm after makes the task far more complex than if done using lynx. I'll now mark this -display_charset=UTF-8 switch suggestion as the solution to my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

lynx does transliteration using your *locale* settings as a hint.  Running in `cron`, it's likely that the locale is POSIX.  I'd investigate that first.

For lynx's configuration, start here:

- [Character Sets](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/cattoc.html#header004) (topic)
- [**`CHARACTER_SET`**](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#CHARACTER_SET)
- [**`LOCALE_CHARSET`**](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#LOCALE_CHARSET)

  > **`LOCALE_CHARSET`** overrides **`CHARACTER_SET`** if true, using the current locale to lookup a MIME name that corresponds, and use that as the display charset.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Thomas Dickey. I did not try this yet, but from what I'm reading adding the line LANG=en_US.UTF-8 to /etc/environment might well address the issue I was experiencing (cron's locale being set to POSIX) with my script and the lynx -dump command.